# How to split a string in a 2D list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string

```
s = 'A;B;C1,C2,C3;D'
```

I want to split this string in a 2D list, so the result would be:

```
alist = [['A'], ['B'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['D']]
```

I can't do that with

```
'A;B;C1,C2,C3;D'.split(';').split(',')
```

because `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Is there an easy way to fill this 2d list at once?

Comment: You will need list comprehension or explicit loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension

```
>>> res = [s1.split(',') for s1 in s.split(';')]
>>> res
[['A'], ['B'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['D']]
```

Comment: That is perfect!